# python nosetests AssertionError: None != 'hmmm...'

Tags: python-2.7, nose, assertion

below is the test I am trying to run:

```
    def test_hmm_method_returns_hmm(self):
    #set_trace()
    assert_equals( orphan_elb_finder.hmm(), 'hmmm...')
```

When I run the code I get the following output:

```
D:\dev\git_repos\platform-health\tests\unit\test_orphan_elb_finder>nosetests
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_hmm_method_returns_hmm (test_orphan_elb_finder.test_basic.BasicTestSuite)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\git_repos\platform-health\tests\unit\test_orphan_elb_finder\test_basic.py", line 18, in test_hmm_method_returns_hmm
    self.assertEqual(orphan_elb_finder.hmm(), 'hmmm...')
AssertionError: None != 'hmmm...'
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
hmmm...

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

It seems to be that orphan_elb_finder.hmm results to None. Which is weird because when I uncomment the set_trace and run the command manually it gives me the correct output:

```
-> assert_equals( orphan_elb_finder.hmm(), 'hmmm...')
(Pdb) orphan_elb_finder.hmm()
hmmm...
```

But when I try and run the same assertion in the debugger:

```
(Pdb) assert_equals(orphan_elb_finder.hmm(), 'hmmm...')
hmmm...
*** AssertionError: None != 'hmmm...'
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the way stdout is used but I'm a little bit lost as to how to find out more information / fix this problem.

Below is the orphan_elb_finder methods:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def get_hmm():
    """Get a thought."""
    return 'hmmm...'

def hmm():
    """Contemplation..."""
    print get_hmm()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

So following Blckknght response I have tried to call get_hmm instead of hmm(). But when I try call the method I get the below error

```
    assert_equals(orphan_elb_finder.get_hmm(), 'hmmm...')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_hmm'
```

Then I try and check available methods

```
(Pdb) dir(orphan_elb_finder)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'core', 'hmm']
```

It seems that the below module does not reveal the get_hmm() method for some reason?

UPDATE 2:

Found out what was going on. Inside my orphan_elb_finder package inside **init**.py I had

```
from .core import hmm
```

changed it to

```
from .core import get_hmm
```

and it seemed to work. Somehow though I think the author of the package construction indented get_hmm to be a private method. Not sure How I would have tested it if that is the case seeing as get_hmm returns None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hmm` method, unlike the `get_hmm` method, does not have a `return` statement. It `print`s the string `"hmmm..."`, but returns `None`.

Compare calling `get_hmm()` and calling `hmm()`. The former will print `'hmmm...'` with the quotation marks. That's because it's returning the string, and the interactive console is printing the `repr` of the return value. In contrast, when you call `hmm()`, it does its own printing (with no quotation marks), then returns `None` (the default return value when nothing else is specified). The interactive console skips printing out the `repr` of the return value when it is `None`, so there's nothing extra printed.

```
>>> get_hmm()
'hmmm...'
>>> hmm()
hmmm...
```

Comment: Thanks mate this makes perfect sense. My next challenge is when i try and run get_hmm() which returns something. It appears that my package cannot reference that function. See updated original question

Comment: It's probably possible to test the printed output from `hmm`, which might be more appropriate if it's the only public API available. But I don't actually know how to write such a test, so I didn't suggest it. Probably you'd need to temporarily replace `sys.stdout` with something (like a `StringIO` object) and then check what got written to it.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have one final question on all this stuff. Inside my orphan_elb_finder package in the __init__.py file I have "from .core import get_hmm" which works. But when I change it to "import .core" I get a syntax error. I guess what I'm asking is how do I import everything from core.py so I dont have to import each individual method? Or is this a bad way of doing it? I'm following the guide here -> http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

Comment: Well, you could do `from .core import *`, which will import everything in `core.py`'s `__all__` global, or every global variable that doesn't start with an underscore if there is no `__all__` defined. However wildcard imports like that are usually discouraged. You might instead want to do `from . import core` (or just not do anything at all at the `__init__.py` file) and have the user code access the submodule themselves. E.g., `import orphan_elb_finder.core`, then call `orphan_elb_finder.core.hmm()`.

Comment: Thanks mate I'll play around and see what I come up wtih

Comment: You may also want to read [official tutorial on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and/or [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) which introduced the relative import syntax you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for all your help mate, will check it out :)